# Assign sequence based on simple calculation

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, dynamic-programming

I'm developing a model for truck sequencing at a warehouse. I want to sequence the trucks based on a value ($Q$) equal to the multiplication of their priority ($\alpha$), arrival time (continuous variable $A_i$), and the load they are carrying ($a_{ik}$). 
$$
Q(i)=\alpha \cdot A_i \cdot  a_{ik}
$$
I know I have to use a binary variable $p_{ij}$ that is $1$ if inbound truck $i$ and $j$ are assigned to the same door and truck $j$ is a predecessor of truck $i$.

How do I make sure it takes into account $Q(i)$ when assigning $p_{ij}$ and write the constraint?

Comment: Should it not be $\alpha_i$ ? and what does the index $k$ refer to?

Comment: K is the type of product.

Answer (score 1):

Let $o_{id}^r$ be a binary variable that takes value $1$ if and ony if truck $i$ has departure rank $r$ on door $d$, and let $y_{id}$ be a binary variable that takes value $1$ if and only if truck $i$ is assigned to door $d$.
Let $\delta_{ij}$ be a binary variables that takes value $1$ if and only if $Q_i > Q_j$.

Constraints :

- Each truck is assigned to exactly one door 
  $$
  \sum_{d} y_{id} = 1 \quad \forall i
  $$
- Each truck has a unique departure rank :
  $$
  \sum_{d,r} o_{id}^r = 1 \quad \forall i
  $$
- If a truck is assigned to door $d$, its rank must be in door $d$:
  $$
  y_{id} \le \sum_{r} o_{id}^r  \quad \forall i,d
  $$
- If $Q_i > Q_j$, activate $\delta_{ij}$ :
  $$
  Q_i - Q_j \le  M \delta_{ij}\quad \forall i,j
  $$
- If a truck $i$ is assigned to door $d$ and has $Q_i$ greater than $Q_j$ for any other truck $j$ assigned to $d$, then its order must be smaller :
  $$
  r o_{id}^r \le s o_{jd}^s + 1 + M(3-y_{jd}-y_{id}-\delta_{ij}) \quad \forall r,o,i,j,d,s
  $$

Comment: I forgot to mention, the order of the trucks is ordered from highest Q to lower Q. The warehouse will process the highest Q first.

Comment: Yes that is what I assumed : if $Q_i > Q_j$, then the rank of $i$ is smaller than the rank of $j$.

Comment: Can you please explain s?

Comment: Can you specify where you need more explanation ?

Comment: r is the rank set [r=1,...,R], what does s represent in the last constraint?
Also can i=j ?

Comment: s in just another rank in the set $1,..,R$, and of course $i\neq j$